# What is The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add contacts to the constant contact site n there  i am getting following exception
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

i am using ASp.net C# application for inserting my records.

can  any one tell me the solution ,or why i am getting the above error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This [website](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/23/understanding-400-bad-request-exception.aspx) is useful.

> **Introduction**:
>
> Why I am getting this exception? What is the cause of this error. Developers are always curious to know the root cause of an
>   exception, even though they found the solution from elsewhere. So what
>   is the reason of this exception (400 Bad Request).The answer is
>   security. Security is an important feature for any application.
>   ASP.NET try to his best to give you more secure application
>   environment as possible. One important security feature is related to
>   URLs. Because there are various ways a hacker can try to access server
>   resource. Therefore it is important to make your application as secure
>   as possible. Fortunately, ASP.NET provides this security by throwing
>   an exception of Bad Request whenever he feels. In this Article I am
>   try to present when ASP.NET feels to throw this exception. You will
>   also see some new ASP.NET 4 features which gives developers some
>   control on this situation.